# How to df.groupby.sum only one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df (see example) that has columns: `master ID`, `sub ID` (child of `master ID`), prices of sub ID and scenarios count for each master ID/SubID. I would like to find the prices pct_change between scenarios for each master ID as displayed in example. master ID price are the sums of their child sub ID prices. Sorry if this is not clear.

what have been tried so far:

```
df.sort_values(by="scenario", ascending=False).groupby('subID').head(n=1)
```

Example of df and desired result

[image: Example of df and desired result]

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: @MaxU I did sort scenario and groupby id as fallow.  df.sort_values(by="scenario", ascending=False).groupby('subID').head(n=1)

Comment: @MaxU I did sort scenario and groupby id to generate df of latest scenario as follow.  df.sort_values(by="scenario", ascending=False).groupby('subID').head(n=1). To sum prices I did df.groupby('masterID').sum() however this sums every column. Wanted to do this logic for last 2 scenarios and then rearrange to desired format however doesn't look like the ideal way to go about solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first step would be to group by master id and scenario, and then unstack scenario to get a column for each one:

```
df_scen = df.groupby(['master id', 'scenario']).agg({'price': 'sum'}).unstack('scenario')
```

The next step would be to create a new column for % change. You may have to play with the column names a bit, but it should look something like this:

```
df_scen['% change'] = 100 * df_scen[('scenario', 2)] / df_scen[('scenario', 1)] - 100
```

### Edit

In case you have several scenarios for each master ID, and you only want the latest two:

```
# Group and sort in descending order of scenario
grp = df.sort_values(['master id', 'scenario'], ascending=False).groupby('master id')

# Get only the latest and previous scenarios
df_first = grp.nth(0).reset_index()  # synonymous to .first()
df_first['rev_scen'] = 'current'
df_second = grp.nth(1).reset_index()
df_second['rev_scen'] = 'previous'

df_latest = df_first.append(df_second) # Merge the two

# From here on it's basically the same as the original answer
df_scen = df_latest.groupby(['master id', 'rev_scen']).agg({'price': 'sum'}).unstack('rev_scen')
df_scen['% change'] = 100 * df_scen[('price', 'current')] / df_scen[('price', 'previous')] - 100
```

Comment: your solution works however I should of mentioned in my initial post that I'd like to be able to only retrieve the last two scenarios. For example if masterID has scenarios [1,2,4,6,9] I only want scenarios 6 and 9 in my columns. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to first create a new column  (say 'rev_scen') containing the scenario number in a reverse count - meaning the latest scenario 0, the previous -1, before that -2 and so on. The you can query for rev_scen >= -1, and then apply my solution. Let me know if you get stuck, and I'll write you a snippet tomorrow, when I get to a computer.

Comment: @Obabs did everything work out or are you still stuck?

Comment: yes still stuck, if I have the same number of scenario for each masterID it works, however I'm running into situations were I have 20 scenarios for one and 5 for another masterID

Comment: That's not a problem, you just need the reverse scenario counter. I have an idea. I'll look into it and let you know

Comment: just needed to add a groupby.sum() for the child id before your solution.Other than that worked great, thanks again

Comment: Right, good catch. You'd have to start with the sum, reset the index and then move on to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
    id  master_id  price  scenario
0  101          1    400         1
1  102          1    550         1
2  101          1    650         2
3  102          1    400         2
4  201          2    500         1
5  201          2    600         2
6  301          2    500         3
7  301          2    600         3

In [39]: g = df.groupby(['master_id','scenario'], as_index=False)['price']\
   ....:       .sum()\
   ....:       .pivot(index='master_id', columns='scenario', values='price')\
   ....:       .reset_index()

In [40]: g
Out[40]:
scenario  master_id      1       2       3
0                 1  950.0  1050.0     NaN
1                 2  500.0   600.0  1100.0
```

Comment: I think this would work if I only had 2 scenarios. I should of mentioned that my df has multiple scenarios and a different scenario count for each masterID. I only need to find the pct_change for last two scenarios

Comment: @Obabs, it'll work for any number of `scenario`s, `master_id`'s, etc. - check my updated answer

Comment: it works for any number of scenarios however I'd like to be able to only retrieve the last two scenarios. For example if masterID has scenarios [1,2,4,6,9] I only want scenarios 6 and 9 in my columns.

Comment: @Obabs, then just filter your DF beforehand